# Converting a single XML attribute of element to child element

Tags: xml, xslt

First of all I want to express my admiration for everybody who understands what's going on in XSLT processing.

Usually, I will found some example on StackOverflow that does what I need, tweak it a little bit, and continue working with C coding :), but this time I'm stuck and don't understand why things are not working.

I have found close enough question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798164/convert-xml-attributes-to-elements-using-xslt)

I modified it to work on a single attribute I need, and it works as expected with the XML example in the original question.

I.e. I can get:

```
<sect id="5" heading="1">
</sect>
```

to be modified to:

```
<sect heading="1">
    <id>5</id>
</sect>
```

Using example [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkntb/5)

But my XML is a bit more complex and 2 problems discovered so far to process it (both presented in the link above):

1. I want the new element to be placed first thing after the original element, but if the free text will 
   appear after the original element the result will be different, i.e new element will be after the text.
2. Something goes wrong while processing the element I modify, for example following:

`<TableCell>User input and actions: for example, type <bold>exit</bold>, click <bold>OK</bold>, press <bold>Alt+C</bold></TableCell>`

will be changed to

`<TableCell>User input and actions: for example, type , click , press <bold>exit</bold><bold>OK</bold><bold>Alt+C</bold></TableCell>`

while it's left untouched if the same line is placed outside the element having attribute I'm modifying. Looking closely at the second problem, it seems to be the same or similar problem as a first one, i.e free text is placed before elements and the original order is not preserved.

Since I fail to understand processing order in XSLT I have no idea how to fix it. 
Any help with this or completely alternative suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Regards, 
Ilya.

Comment: Consider to include any relevant code like XML and XSLT and output you want versus the one you get in the question, only use online tools as an additional description of the problem as otherwise any readers of your question or any answer can't understand the problem if the online tool link doesn't work.

Comment: I see your point. In this specific case, I think there is no point to quote my incorrect XSL code. Martin provided a simple and elegant solution for requested functionality which is presented in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might suffice to first process the attributes you want to copy as attributes with one apply-templates (or simply use copy-of for them) and to then apply-templates to the id attribute and any child nodes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='id')]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@id">
      <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkntb/7

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is simple, elegant, and do what is needed. 
If you could explain the node() part of <xsl:apply-templates select="@id | node()"/> it will be really great. Any why node() is not needed in the first invocation of apply-templates.

Comment: In `<xsl:apply-templates select="@id | node()"/>` the `id` attribute and all child `node()`s are processed, and of course in document order. So `node()` there means all child nodes. See also https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#node-tests.